# Yeoman Generator Next Steps

Tags: yeoman-generator

I'm new to creating a Yeoman Generator. I used generator-generator to get me started and I went through the process of creating it, testing, and getting it all buttoned up.

In the tuts for creating a yo generator they seem to leave off where my question is headed.

Question: What next? I've got it all readyL

- Do I submit it to Yeoman?
- Simply put it on my Github?
- How can I get it to where others can start using my shiny new generator?

Thanks for the help / guidance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Found here: http://www.eguneys.com/blog/2014/09/17/lets-build-a-yeoman-generator-2

**Publish Your Generator**

Finally you can publish your generator. First create an account on npm. Next set your npm author info.

```
$ npm set init.author.name "Your Name"
$ npm set init.author.email "Your Email"
$ npm set init.author.url "Your Website"

$ npm adduser
```

Then publish with.

```
$ npm publish
```

A note about the package.json format

There is a list of yeoman generators in the official yeoman website. It is automatically pulled from the npm API. To list your generator there you need to add `yeoman-generator` keyword to your `package.json` and a repository description on Github.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to publish it to [npm](http://npmjs.org).

Make sure to add `"yeoman-generator"` as a keywords in your package.json file so it'll be listed on yeoman.io and by `yo` when a user search for generators.