# npm published yeoman generator not showing under yeoman.io

Tags: yeoman, yeoman-generator

I have recently written a yeoman generator called ['generator-webvr-decorator'](https://github.com/vt5491/generator-webvr-decorator).  Following the instructions from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28847456/yeoman-generator-next-steps/28883794#28883794), I have done all the steps including [publishing to npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/generator-webvr-decorator).  However, after four days I do still not see my generator listed under the [yeoman generators web page](http://yeoman.io/generators/).  The number of generators seems to be frozen at 3438.

I have done all the following:

- npm test passes.
- I have 'yeoman-generator' in the package.json keywords:

```

```
 {
    "name": "generator-webvr-decorator",
    "version": "0.1.5",
    "description": "add WebVr boilerplate to an existing application",
    "license": "MIT",
    "main": "app/index.js",
    "repository": "vt5491/generator-webvr-decorator",
    "author": {
        "name": "vt5491",
        "email": "vt5491@gmail.com",
        "url": "https://github.com/vt5491"
    },
    "scripts": {
        "test": "mocha"
    },
    "files": [
        "generators",
        "lib"
    ],
    "keywords": [
        "yeoman-generator",
        "webvr",
        "vr",
        "angular"
    ],
    "dependencies": {
        "async": "^1.5.0",
        "chalk": "^1.0.0",
        "cheerio": "^0.19.0",
        "escope": "^3.3.0",
        "esprima": "^2.7.0",
        "jquery": "^2.1.4",
        "jsonfile": "^2.2.3",
        "lodash": "^3.10.1",
        "merge": "^1.2.0",
        "yeoman-generator": "^0.19.0",
        "yosay": "^1.0.2"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "mocha": "*"
    }
}
```

```

- published to npm.  It is found by the npm search:

> ```
>    turner@vturner-virtual-machine ~/vtstuff/github2/generator-webvr-decorator $ npm search
> ```
>
> generator-webvr-decorator
>       NAME                      DESCRIPTION                                      AUTHOR  DATE       VERSION KEYWORDS
>       generator-webvr-decorator add WebVr boilerplate to an existing application =vt5491 2015-12-05 0.1.4   yeoman-generator webvr vr

- Manually tested installing from the npm repository under windows and linux, so I know it physically works assuming yeoman does some kind of automated testing i.e checks to see if the generator actually runs.

Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

How often is the database of generators under yeoman.io updated?

Should I open a ticket with the yeoman web site?

I don't know what the add rate for generators is, but in the last four days the generator count has stayed constant at 3438.

Many Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The system fetching new generators is currently down: https://github.com/yeoman/yeoman-generator-list/issues/38 - It'll hopefully be up in the next few days.

We're also currently posting packages with `yeoman-generator` keywords that we exclude for other reason here: https://github.com/yeoman/yeoman-generator-list/issues/36 (I don't see yours in there, so your generator will show up soon)

Comment: It now appears under the yeoman web site as of 2015-12-10.  Thank you.